# How to get scrollbar working for expandable items in Listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view which has a Listbox of Studio, Actor and Category items on it. Each Studio, Actor and Category item has a template which is built up with an expander and inside this more items. I want to have a scrollbar for the Listbox so that when I expand one of the Studio / Actor / Category items and these take up more than the size of the window it scrolls the items in this Listbox. This might not be working since there are 'only' 3 items, but the items inside these items are pushing them off the window and this is why I want to be able to scroll the outer Listbox container itself.

This is my code for that main view (the relevant line is the scrollviewer and Listbox, commented --HERE--)

```
<Window x:Class="FileNameTagger.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileNameTagger"
        xmlns:tagTypes="clr-namespace:FileNameTagger.TagTypes"
        xmlns:shared="clr-namespace:Shared;assembly=Shared"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="600" Width="1080" 
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        Background="Transparent"
        ShowInTaskbar="True"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        WindowState="Normal"
        SizeToContent="Manual"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tagTypes:TextListTagTypeViewModel}">
            <tagTypes:TextListTagTypeView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tagTypes:TextTagTypeViewModel}">
            <tagTypes:TextTagTypeView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tagTypes:EnumTagTypeViewModel}">
            <tagTypes:EnumTagTypeView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tagTypes:DateTagTypeViewModel}">
            <tagTypes:DateTagTypeView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Border Background="RoyalBlue">
            <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <MenuItem Header="_File" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" >
                    <MenuItem Header="_Load File"
                          Command ="{Binding AddFileCommand}">
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_New Tag"
                          Command="{Binding ClearTagCommand}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Export Tag"
                          Command="{Binding SaveTagCommand}"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Templates" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" >
                    <MenuItem Header="_Import Tag Template"
                          Command ="{Binding ImportTagTemplateCommand}">
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
             
            <Grid Grid.Row ="1" x:Name ="ChildViews">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,0,5,5">Selected File:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding LoadedFile.Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TagTypesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TagTypeViewModels}"/><!--HERE-->
                </ScrollViewer>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ExportedTag">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">Exported Tag:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ExportedTag}" Margin="5"></TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                </Grid>
            
            </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

And this is the data template for those Studio / Category / Actor items

```
<DataTemplate x:Key ="TextListTagTypeItemDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="3" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateTagDataCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Padding="10,10,10,10"
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                >
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                        Kind="ContentSave"
                                        Height="12"
                                        Padding="0,10,10,0"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Grid.Column="4" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteTagCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Padding="10,10,10,10"
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                >
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon
                                        Kind="TrashCanCircle"
                                        Height="12"
                                        Padding="0,10,10,0"/>
                        </Button>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </CheckBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Screenshots of what happens when I expand the items:

Un-expanded
[image]

Expanded (scrollbar doesn't scroll)
[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the vertical space given to the `ScrollViewer` for it to be working. Currently it is positioned in the first row of your `ChildViews` grid which is set to "Auto" (meaning: "use as much space as you need"). Nesting the `ChildViews` grid into the outermost grid removes the restriction to the screen size (meaning: the outer grid is restricted to the screen size, but `ChildViews` produces overflow *below* the screen, which is the reason for only the upper scroll arrow being visible).

As far as I can see it, you don't need to nest the first two grids. Maybe you can even avoid the third grid. I'd suggest, you start with one grid containing your menu and the `ListBox` and see, what it looks like. Then add the remaining elements (one by one).

Furthermore you don't need to define a single `ColumnDefinition` and you don't have to wrap your `ListBox` in a `ScrollViewer`, as it already has a scroll bar/viewer.